# Intersection of geometric entities

Tags: c++, c++11, idioms, geometry, return-type

I was trying to design a small C++ geometric API for learning purposes, but came across a problem when dealing with intersections of geometric entities. For example, the intersection of a line and a sphere can have three different types: a couple of points, a point or nothing at all. I found several ways to deal with this problem, but I don't know which of them seems to be the best:

### CGAL `Object` return type

I first tried to see what was done in other geometric libraries. The most complete I can found was CGAL. In CGAL, intersection functions return an `Object` which is a generic type that can hold anything (like `boost::any`). Then, you try to assign the `Object` to a value of another type, here is an example:

```
void foo(CGAL::Segment_2<Kernel> seg, CGAL::Line_2<Kernel> line)
{
    CGAL::Object result;
    CGAL::Point_2<Kernel> ipoint;
    CGAL::Segment_2<Kernel> iseg;

    result = CGAL::intersection(seg, line);
    if (CGAL::assign(ipoint, result)) {

        // handle the point intersection case.

    } else if (CGAL::assign(iseg, result)) {

        // handle the segment intersection case.

    } else {

       // handle the no intersection case.
    }
}
```

By the way, the `assign` function uses `dynamic_cast` to check whether the two variables are assignable (everybody loves RTTI).

### Union return type

A union can also be used as a return type, but it means using an `id` for every geometric type and having some kind of variant type to cover all the problems.

```
struct Variant
{
    int id;
    union
    {
        Point point;
        std::pair<Point, Point> pair;
    };
};

int main()
{
    Point point;
    std::pair<Point, Point> pair;

    Variant v = intersection(Line{}, Sphere{});
    if (v.id == ID_POINT)
    {
        point = v.point;
        // Do something with point
    }
    else if (v.id == ID_VARIANT)
    {
        pair = v.pair;
        // Do something with pair
    }
    else
    {
        // No intersection
    }
}
```

### Avoiding the "no intersection" problem

In order to split the "no intersection" case from the main problem, some libraries used to require the user to check whether there was an intersection before trying to find what was the intersection return type. It looked like this:

```
Line line;
Sphere sphere;

if (intersects(line, sphere))
{
    auto ret = intersection(line, sphere);
    // Do something with ret
}
```

Another way to split the "no intersection" case from the rest of the problem would be to use an `optional` type:

```
std::optional<...> ret = intersection(Line{}, Sphere{});
if (ret)
{
    // Do something with ret
}
```

### Using exceptions to control the "return" type

*I can already see some of you crying.*

Yet another way to handle that problem of having different return types would be to `throw` the results instead of returning them. The "no intersection" return could still use one of the techniques from the previous paragraph:

```
try
{
    intersection(Line{}, Sphere{});
}
catch (const Point& point)
{
    // Do something with point
}
catch (const std::pair<Point, Point>& pair)
{
    // Do something with pair
}
// Can still catch errors (or "no intersection" special type?)
```

### Having a "main" return type, throwing the other ones

Another way would be to have a "main" return type for the intersection, let's say `std::pair<Point, Point>` and considering the other return types as "exceptional"; it gives more meaning to the use of exceptions while this is still not quite an error gestion. On the other hand, it could seem strange to handle a "main" type differently than the others...

```
try
{
    auto pair = intersection(Line{}, Sphere{});
    // Do something with pair
}
catch (const Point& point)
{
    // The chances for a sphere and a line to meet at
    // a single point are so small that the case can
    // already be considered exceptional.
    // ...
}
```

I purposedly left the errors gestion and the "no intersection" case out of this last example since many techniques already described could be used to handle it and I don't want the number of examples to be exponential. Here is one though:

```
try
{
    // res is optional<pair<Point, Point>>
    if (auto res = intersection(Line{}, Sphere{}))
    {
        std::cout << "intersection: two points" << '\n'
                  << std::get<0>(*res).x() << " "
                  << std::get<0>(*res).y() << '\n'
                  << std::get<1>(*res).x() << " "
                  << std::get<1>(*res).y() << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "no intersection" << '\n';
    }
}
catch (const Point& point)
{
    // Exceptional case
    std::cout << "intersection: one point" << '\n'
              << point.x() << " "
              << point.y() << '\n';
}
```

Since the cases where the result is thrown are exceptional, it should not add any runtime overhead to the program if the underlying system uses zero cost exceptions instead of the old SJLJ exceptions system.

### The actual question

Well, that was a pretty long introduction, so here is the question: is there an idiomatic solution to the problem in these examples? And if not, are there at least some of the examples which could be banned without a second thought (well, [you could give a second thought to the exception examples](http://www.drmaciver.com/2009/03/exceptions-for-control-flow-considered-perfectly-acceptable-thanks-very-much/) though...)?

**Note:** something seemed evident to me but apparently is not: the entity returned by intersection between two geometric entities is not limited to a nothing, a point or a set of point. An intersection can pretty much return any geometric entity. Therefore, using a container to hold the values does not sound like a good idea.

**Note 2:** time machine note, it happens. After having given it some thought, I would ban exceptions (as most people would do), not because exceptions are inherently bad or not designed for this, but because it makes the expression `intersection(...) == SomeShape` throw an exception even when the both operands should be equal, which isn't elegant. I guess that I would use a bastard child of a variant instead.

Comment: Can intersection be something else than collection of points?

Comment: @Euphoric In the intersection of two lines, the intersection can be the line itself for example.

Comment: Why not return a generic polymorphic intersection type from the collision detection algorithm and then use a variant of the Visitor pattern to dispatch handling based on the dynamic types of several (two?) intersection objects when you need it? Otherwise using virtual functions seems straightforward enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are working on a geometric API, I guess you are not only
interested in intersection of lines and spheres, but have also more
exciting projects.

A natural approach to solve your problem of representing values for
intersection would be to define a type for geometric figures so that
you can represent:

- Points
- Lines
- Spheres
- Intersections that you cannot compute (kind of symbolic intersection)
- Union of figures

Once you have done that, your intersection algorithm can gobble two
figures and return a figure, computed by using

(A + B + ...).(C + D + ...) = A.C + A.D + B.C + B.D + ...

where I denote the union by `+` and the intersection by `.` and where
A, B, C, D and the dots can be a point, a sphere, a line or an
intersection you cannot compute.

To some extent, this approach gives satisfying results and may give
the feeling that it is the right solution to the problem.

There are however a lot of problems with this approach, that you
should be aware of:

1. Intersection that you cannot compute tend to absorb everything,
   i.e. intersecting anything with an intersection that you cannot can
   yield an intersection that you cannot compute.
2. If you intersect two spheres, it yields a circle, that you cannot
   compute, not because you cannot find which circle it is, but
   because you cannot represent circles.  If you choose to add circles
   to your vocabulary, you have to figure out how to compute
   intersections with all other figures you may have. So if you have
   *n* base figures you should deal with *n^2* type of
   intersections. So, choosing a rich vocabulary of figures without
   relying on ``intersections you cannot compute'' is not an option.
3. Even if you restrict yourself to the rassuring realm of algebraic
   figures (defined by polynomial equations), computing intersections
   is far from trivial.  What you are trying to do is to *compute a
   minimal set of generators of the reduced ideal* defined by your
   intersection, so do not expect to be able to do this on more than a
   few examples. You should regard anything you are able to compute as
   a lucky accident.

Comment: Well, I'm already aware of the problem of intersections generating new shapes. I only designed a simplified library, so I thought I would just document which intersections are computable. I do not aim to make it a super-generic library either :)
CGAL (which is wayyyyy bigger tant what I'm trying to do) uses the same approach: it documents which intersections are computable and consider all the other ones as not computable.

Answer (score 2):

the solutions that I would use or have seen used are:

1. use a *container* to return intersection points

   more expandable for other geometric entities that may have more intersections but has more overhead
2. return *invalid* points when no intersection

   you need have a concept of validness for the data type, or have an `optional` type
3. use a *callback function* that gets called each time an intersection is found

   this one allows for specific processing without needing to collect all points

the ones I would BAN out of hand are the ones using exceptions, exception handling is slow and many people with crucify you for doing this

Comment: Oh yeah, also: returning a container would be great if I only returned points. Thing is intersection can potentially return any geometric type. I could still return a container of `Shape` instances, but I would still need RTTI for it to work :/

Answer (score 1):

You have listed many valid alternatives, however the straightforward one is missing:

Just return the count of intersections, and return the points via an array argument. The array argument, of course, has a size to fit the maximum count of intersections. Something like this:

```
size_t getIntersections(const Sphere& sphere, const Ray& ray, std::array<Point, 2>* intersections);
```

This is just as safe or unsafe as the `union` approach or the one that returns illegal points. However, it has one clear advantage: You do not force user code to differentiate between the three cases. I. e., instead of having an if-else ladder along the lines

```
auto result = intersections(...);
if(/*no intersection*/) {
    ...
} else if(/*one intersection*/) {
    ...
} else /*two intersections*/ {
    ...
}
```

the calling site may choose to say

```
arrays<Point, 2> points;
for(size_t i = getIntersections(..., &points); i--; ) {
    /*code to handle points[i]*/
}
```

That is not possible if the count of intersections is somehow encoded in the return type of the function.

---

And, yes, I would also discard anything with exceptions without a second thought. They are brutally slow unless they are optimized away. And for optimization you would need to disclose the intersection calculating code to the calling site.

Comment: Exceptions are brutally slow except when not called. In one of the examples, I returned the most case and threw the "exceptional" ones which are statistically brutally uncommon, so the speed should not have been a problem. I wouldn't choose the exceptions for other reasons, though :)

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem with your solution is that it only works when the result of the intersection is a set a points. However, an intersection between two lines can return a point, a line or nothing. Bottom line: the result can be a set of widely different shapes, so an array of one type can't do it :/